# How hard is it to enable TFS to use SSL?

Tags: tfs

How hard is it to enable TFS to start using secure connections, if its not already?  Does doing so affect SQL configuration also? How can we force SSL to be required?

Im looking over this reference material
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#DisAd

Reading the above, I get the impression that MS is trying to discourage someone from using SSL for TFS over the internet?

Then I stumbled on to this blocg post
http://www.jwsecure.com/2009/01/29/using-tfs-via-the-internet/
Summary = just get a ssl cert and force ssl and port-forward a high port to 443

thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) you posted above shows you the detailed steps on how to set up HTTPS with SSL for TFS. To summarize main steps include:

1. Install a certification authority, **obtain** and install a server certificate for servers.
2. Request, install and configure websites with a certificate for Team Foundation Server using Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
3. Configure Team Foundation Server to require HTTPS and SSL.
4. Install the certificate on client computers.

You can also check this walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833873.aspx

Secondly, you don't need to configure SQL Server. But if you have SQL Reporting Service, you need to configure it to support HTTPS with SSL.

Thirdly, to enable TFS to be available with external connections, you need to configure it with HTTPS with SSL. Also with it, web connections to TFS are more secure. However, these process needs more administrator's configuration & maintenance work. So you need to determine whether to use it based on your requirement.